# Чем отличается объект jQuery от обычного элемента DOM?

Tags: jquery, javascript, dom

Объясните популярно. Ссылки - скользкая тема. Никогда она мне не открывалась полностью.
В чем разница:

```
this - элемент DOM
$(this) - объект jQuery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В js существуют объекты, всякие разные. функция `$()` возвращает объект jQuery, это просто js объект с какими-то своими методами и свойствами (заданно в библиотеке jquery), а DOM объект это другой объект, у него другие свойства и методы. Упрощенно jquery объект похож на DOM объект примерно как а на b в этом примере:

```
var $ = (function () {
    function el() {}
    el.prototype.elements = [];
    el.prototype.add = function (element) {
        this.elements.push(element);
        return this;

    };
    return function (element) {
        return new el().add(element);
    };
})();

var a = document.getElementById('test');
var b = $(a);
console.log(a, b);
```

(т.е. не похож вовсе)

Answer (score 2):

Язык один - javascript, зн реализация this только одна. This указывает на контекст вызова.

Когда вы пишите $(this) вызывается ф-ия jquert.fn.init, она очень страшная, но в итоге возвращается [обычный jquery объект](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.x-master/src/core/init.js#L102) . Т.е элемент указывает на ноду,а jquery объект имеет свойства length и context.

Answer (score -1):

```
this - чистый js
$(this) - jQuery
```

Например, если вы в функции используете this, то цепочка jquery функций не будет работать. Будет работать цепочка функций чистого js

Comment: а теперь объясните за что минусы

Comment: не знаю, поставлю плюс :D По мне так я тоже фигово ответил.

Comment: this - указывает на контекст.

$(this) - создает экземпляр объекта https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L30

Вы должны сами понять, что ваш ответ может быть и имеет право на существование, но к вопросу совершенно не относится.